# Core data context.save() only inserted managed objects (ios)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In core data stack with SQLite, when terminating an app I would like to persist managed objects in viewContext serving whatever viewControllers. The difficult part is in doing so for updated and deleted managed objects only when accessible is cloud server where the true copy of these objects' info stays.  In other words, if there is no connection to cloud server, I only persist inserted objects in a viewContext.  Is there a solution for this logic?

Comment: It's hard to understand what problem you're having here.

Comment: My problem is I only want to store inserted managed object to SQLite should network be unavailable. Other types of managed objects such as updated or deleted in context will be saved to cloud first and then save to local SQLite in the former callback block. By this design I try to aovid troubling users to choose which version of a record they want to keep if there is inconsistency between local and server copy of same record info.)